Shedding kitten
My kitten is four months old and she has longer hair. She is shedding like crazy and the hair gets in my face and itches so bad. I have been brushing her and even got her shampoo just for this. Is there anything else I can do to help?? I love her and getting rid of her it's a option.

If it turns out that you are allergic to the cat, I do know folks who have simply gone on antihistamines for years so they can have a cat. With the modern drugs side effects are much less of a problem... but they are more expensive that the older small-molecule antihistamines.
